# error when adding a value to the array state in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to add a value to the array conditionally.
This is the state and the add function:

```
const [Selectors, setSelectors] = useState([]);
const SelectorAdd = (newValue) => {
   setSelectors((array) => [...array, newValue]);
}
```

And I just want to add an arbitrary value to the array `Selectors` inside this just condition:

```
{Yes ?
   <>
      <AnyComponent />
      {SelectorAdd('text value')} <=== this
   </>
: null}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

Can you please tell me where I made this mistake?

Thank you!

Comment: The logic currently expressed is such that on every render you update state, which triggers a re-render, which updates state, etc., etc.  Surely this isn't what you want to do.  So when *should* this state be updated?  In response to an event of some kind?  Once when the component first loads?  Something else?

Comment: @David, Thanks for the clarification! The error has been corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you run `SelectorAdd` you change the state of the component and so rerender the component, which runs `SelectorAdd` which rerenders the component...etc.  You've got to separate the logic from the JSX.  Pass it to a function defined elsewhere in the component, for instance.

Comment: Fixed the error another way! Thank you!